# Elasticsearch: illegal_argument_exception - Failed to bulk insert with elastic dump

Tags: elasticsearch

There are 23000 records fetch from Database and formatted in to JSON. I need to insert each one as a document in Elasticsearch and `autocomplete_entities` index. The input file looks like this

```
[
    {
        "id" : 1,
        "title" : "x"
    },
    {
        "id" : 2,
        "title" : "y"
    },
    ...
]
```

This is the bash code I am working with

> elasticdump --input=PycharmProjects/untitled/vendors.json --output=http://localhost:9200     /autocomplete_entities/_doc --type=data --transform="doc._source=Object.assign({},doc)"    --limit=1000

I got this code from [this link](https://github.com/elasticsearch-dump/elasticsearch-dump/issues/534). After running the code I receive this error:

```
Thu, 01 Oct 2020 10:57:34 GMT | starting dump
Thu, 01 Oct 2020 10:57:34 GMT | Will modify documents using these scripts: doc._source=Object.assign({},doc)
Thu, 01 Oct 2020 10:57:35 GMT | got 1 objects from source file (offset: 0)
{ _index: 'autocomplete_entities',
_type: '_doc',
_id: 'bpnP43QB8j0CMKYkavN7',
status: 400,
error:
{ type: 'illegal_argument_exception',
    reason:
    'Limit of total fields [1000] in index [autocomplete_entities] has been exceeded' } }
Thu, 01 Oct 2020 10:57:41 GMT | sent 1 objects to destination elasticsearch, wrote 0
Thu, 01 Oct 2020 10:57:41 GMT | got 0 objects from source file (offset: 1)
Thu, 01 Oct 2020 10:57:41 GMT | Total Writes: 0
Thu, 01 Oct 2020 10:57:41 GMT | dump complete
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your index, you crossed the limit of 1000 fields which caused the exception, please refer [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html#mapping-limit-settings) ES doc for more info,

You can also change this default limit and fix the issue, although if its not intended please try to fix it as more than 1000 fields in index can cause performance and several other issues.

**Request to increase the limit**

PUT http://localhost:9200//_settings

```
{
    "index.mapping.total_fields.limit" : 2000
}
```

Comment: Im new to Elasticdump. I tried this `elasticdump --input=PycharmProjects/untitled/vendors.json --output=http://localhost:9200/autocomplete_entities/_doc --type=data --transform="doc._source=Object.assign({},doc)" --limit=2` and it still reports error

Comment: One more thing, every document has 2 fields. Why it says I exceeded 1000 fields?

Comment: I set ths limit to `30000`, but still receive error : `Limit of total fields [30000] in index [autocomplete_entities] has been exceeded`

Comment: @MamaD looks like you are using the dyamic mapping which is creating the new fields for each of your document, which is causing even 30k limit , you need to def fix this issue but its a different issue

Comment: @MamaD you need to ask a seprate question related to elasticdump and provide related info to it to fix the root cause of creating the new field , btw may i know how you have defined your index mapping ??

Comment: No mapping defined for index

Comment: @MamaD please define so, to avoid this issue, use static mapping to get rid of it

Comment: Ok, I do it and let you know what happens next

Comment: After defining mapping and running console code I get this error `'Rejecting mapping update to [autocomplete_entities] as the final mapping would have more than 1 type: [_doc, autocomplete_entities]'` but no error without mapping. I set limit to 1,000,000

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222365/discussion-between-opster-elasticsearch-ninja-and-m-a-m-a-d).